# asynchronous initialisation with swiftui

Tags: swiftui

Basically - I run up against this a lot - I don't understand how you correctly do asynchronous initialisation in swift with callbacks. (with combine - I can do it). In particular - I have this code:

```swift
struct MyView : View {
    @State var initialised : Bool = false

    init()
    {
       var initialisedBinding = $initialised
       Photos.PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization {
          status in 
          if (status == Photos.PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
              print("here I am")
              initialisedBinding.wrappedValue = true
              initialisedBinding.update()
          }
      }
   }

   var body : some View {
     VStack {
       if (initialised) {
           Text("yep")
       } else {
           Text("nope")
       } 
    } 
  }
```

And when I run it - I get the print out - but the text never changes - it always remains "nope".  What am I doing wrong, and how do I do it right?   (Without using combine - I can do it with like a currentValueSubject and a .onreceive - but it's extra overhead, and I really want to know why the above code doesn't work - obviously I'm understanding something bad)

Comment: In SwiftUI, views are not supposed to be long-lived and have a lifecycle - they are just structures to describe the view. They get initialized and destroyed by SwiftUI as needed, whenever something changes. Anything async should live in a view model that a view "observes" and reacts to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is not ready in `init` yet, so you bound to nowhere. Moreover such activity in `init` is not good, because view can be created many times during rendering. The more appropriate place is `.onAppear`

```
struct MyView : View {
   @State var initialised : Bool = false

   var body : some View {
     VStack {
       if (initialised) {
           Text("yep")
       } else {
           Text("nope")
       } 
    }.onAppear {
       Photos.PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization {
          status in 
          if (status == Photos.PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
              print("here I am")
              self.initialised = true
          }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome - that's what I was looking for (and had never heard of) - thanks!